# Error posting form values using jQuery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have made a simple page which uses jquerydatepicker, two dropdown comboboxes for selecting  time values. I tried to post the values but the page gets redirected to itself with selected values shown in url and I get no values on the receiver page.

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
    var jQueryDatePicker1Opts = {
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
      changeMonth: false,
      changeYear: false,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      showAnim: 'fadeIn'
   };

   $("#jQueryDatePicker1").datepicker(jQueryDatePicker1Opts);
   $("#jQueryDatePicker1").datepicker("setDate", "new Date()");
   $('#submit').click(function() {
  var startTime = parseInt($('#Combobox1 option:selected').text());
  var endTime = parseInt($('#Combobox2 option:selected').text());

  if(startTime>=endTime){
         alert("End Time should not be less than Start Time !");
     return false;
      }         
   });
   $("#Campaign_form").submit(function(){  
 $.post({type:'POST', url:'campaigndata.php' ,
            data:$('#Campaign_form').serialize(), success: function(response) {
                $('#Campaign_form').find('.form_result').html(response);
    }});
    var isValid = $.validate.form(this);
         return isValid;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the form script:

```
 <form name="Campaign_form" id="Campaign_form" >
      <input type="text" id="jQueryDatePicker1" name="jQueryDatePicker1" value="06/09/2012">
      <select name="StartTime" size="1" id="Combobox1" >
         <option value="1">01:00</option>
         ...
         <option value="24">23:00</option>
      </select>
      <select name="EndTime" size="1" id="Combobox2" >
         <option value="1">01:00</option>
          ...
         <option value="24">00:00</option>
      </select>
      <select name="SelectApp" size="1" id="Combobox3" >
      <?php 
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             echo "<option value =".$row['AppName'].">".$row['AppName']."</option>";
          }
      ?>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
   </form>
```

Here is the campaigndata.php script:

```
 <?php
    $campaignDate =  $_POST['jQueryDatePicker1'];
    $camp_Start_Time =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['StartTime']);
    $camp_End_Time =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EndTime']);
    $campaignID = $appid.$campaignDate.$camp_Start_Time ;   
 ?>
```

This campaigndata.php shows null values on echoing above php variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to your database before you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` and change the form method to post.

Comment: hey thanks for reply !! but that is done ..i have exclude that part ...  assume i am getting values in combobox3 from database . ok .
now please provide me the sol.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return false if you don't refresh page by submitting form

```
$("#Campaign_form").submit(function () {
    var isValid = $.validate.form(this);
    if (isValid)
        $.post({type:'POST', url:'campaigndata.php',
            data:$('#Campaign_form').serialize(), success:function (response) {
                $('#Campaign_form').find('.form_result').html(response);
            }});

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

ur answers helped me a lot !!! i figured out the problem  was in capaigndata.php

i was using mysql_real_escape_string() before $_POST[''] ;

which was creating problems .
 I removed those and used normal $_POST[] and it worked magically !!! :)